# How do I loop through an array in javascript to get a new array whose length is not greater than 4?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, filter

I have this array whose length could be any number but not less than 4. How do I loop through this array to get a new array that has a length not greater than 4? I tried using the filter method but it returned an empty array.

This is my attempt:

```js
// array could be of any length but not less than 4.
const projects = [
  'landing page',
  'portfolio page',
  'e-commerce app',
  'Dapps',
  'signup page',
  // ... even more
];

const newProjects = projects.filter((project, index, array) => {
  return project[index <= 4]
})

console.log(newProjects);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `slice()` for this:

```js
const projects = ['landing page', 'portfolio page', 'e-commerce app', 'Dapps', 'signup page'];

console.log(projects.slice(0,4));
```

[Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a portion of an existing array without modifying it.

Comment: length not greater than 4! slice 0,3

Comment: @IharDziamidau ... nope.

Answer (score 3):

Corrected your approach;

```
const projects = ['landing page', 'portfolio page', 'e-commerce app', 'Dapps', 'signup page',.....] // array could be of any length but not less than 4

const newProjects = projects.filter((project, index, array) => {
  return index < 4;
})

console.log(newProjects);
```

Keep in mind that Array has zero-based index.

Proposed solution:

```
const newProjects = projects.slice(0,3);
```

Comment: Thanks the solution using the filter method worked

Comment: @IharDziamidau ... are you aware of [how the `end` parameter of slice works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#parameters)? Test your own code (... `projects.slice(0,3)` ...) before you criticize other dev's approaches.